# How to manage duplicate geometry in Repeat Zones?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to achieve the building in, and animating of elements of a pressure gauge.
In particular, I am trying to use a repeat zone in geometry nodes so that I can animate in the tick marks and pressure readings which are typically printed on a pressure gauge face.

I can animate in and array the tick marks super easy, but the pressure readings are giving me some grief. You can see here how my text is being duplicated.

[image: HERE's my problem]

I have a counter within the repeat zone which adds an integer of 1 for every iteration, and that counter is then multiplied by 1000 to give me KiloPascal readings by every 1000KPa or 1 Bar of atmospheric pressure. I use a join geometry node within the repeat zone to add the iterated geometry so that new instances are "spawned" and rotated but then it writes everything on top of itself for every repetition.
What am I doing wrong here? Or rather, how can I do this better, and correctly?

Here is my node tree. Notice that I have a switch geometry node which outputs nothing when the counter is at zero.

[image: Repeat Zone Node tree which needs some taming]

The Handy Translator Tool is just a simple node group I've made for myself which is essentially a Transform Geometry node on steroids giving much more fine-grained and accurate control of placement using Blender's standard sliders without needing the shift modifier for millimetre size (and smaller) movements.

Comment: If you're generating the entire set of captions on each frame, and add it to a previous frame in a simulation zone, then that's what would should be expected to happen. The generation of a meter like that shouldn't be animated, it should be static. The animated part should be just the rotation of the handle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have someone giving me art direction already, so I'm trying to spawn the tick marks and values in using the iterations/counter as driver. As the iterations increase, each new tick mark and pressure reading must appear.
At the same time their array angle in relation to one another is also dynamically updated in the repeat zone, so they are rotating around the face and sliding into place, adjusting space between each other as they spawn.
I get what you say about generating the entire set of captions in each frame, and it is precisely this which I want to not do.

Comment: Should the "1000" value (for example) remain at the same angular position when the "2000" value is added next iteration, or should it rotate ?

Comment: @StefLAncien It should rotate out with the tick marks.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ah! Bing! The light just went on. I still don't know how to solve it, but I do understand what you're saying. Joining the geometry is outputting the new instance on top of the previous instances. So maybe I should phrase this a different way.
I know how to create an animation with a radial array of tick marks being added in while being rotated around a dial using standard modifiers and an empty as the radial driver. I thought I knew how to use this concept in geo nodes to instance nuts around a flange on industrial piping, using repeat zones, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I want to animate in a growing number of tick marks, accompanied by their procedurally driven 1000KPa intervals for a pressure gauge using a single geometry nodes tree. How should I do that?